# Cannot assign value of type Player to type SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am working on my game everything seems to be going great, but I keep getting this error message 
This is the piece of code the error is on. Player is a class

`player = Player(node: player, particles: playerParticles!)`

```
 func addPlayer() {
    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player.png")
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.size)
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Plyer.rawValue //sets value to 1
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue //will make contact with any value 2
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue //will collide with any value 2
    let playerParticles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "")
    playerParticles?.isHidden = true
    player = Player(node: player, particles: playerParticles!)
    player.addChild(playerParticles!)
    addChild(player)
```

Here is the player class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Player {
    var playerr:SKSpriteNode
    var speed = 0.1
    var showParticles = false
    var particlesFrameCount = 0
    var maxParticleFrames = 20
    var particles:SKEmitterNode
    init(node:SKSpriteNode, particles:SKEmitterNode) {
        self.playerr = node
        self.particles = particles
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: `var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player.png")` gives the `player` variable an implicit type of `SKSpriteNode`. Why would you reassign it with a value of type `Player`? Does `Player` inherit from `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: The error is that player if of type SKSpriteNode and that's how you created it, but then you're trying to create it as a Player object, which it can't do because it's of type SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
func addPlayer() {
var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player.png")
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.size)
player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Plyer.rawValue //sets value to 1
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue //will make contact with any value 2
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue //will collide with any value 2
  self.addChild(player)

let playerParticles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "")
playerParticles?.isHidden = true
self.addChild(playerParticles)
```